# 2 computers 1 wifi connection 1 ethernet connection bridge?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, ubuntu-12.04

My computer setup is very strange not being able to ethernet directly to my network. I have 2 terminals(desktop computers) both running linux(ubuntu 12.04.04 server).

I have attempted to use brctl and iptables to share the internet between these two, to no avail.

I have one computer setup with a wifi card connecting it to my wifi router and then to the internet (that all works...). I am trying to connect another terminal to that one using an ethernet cable and the sharing the wifi internet between these two... At the moment the other computer does not and will not have a wifi card for a while. I want them both to be able to access the internet without porting all of the internet to the one connected through the ethernet cable. Also I wanted them to be fault tolerant so that if one or the other went down when they both were up again they would reconnect to each other (I thought I could do that with dhcp).

as a side note I use ufw(uncomplicated firewall) on terminal_1 as I use it as a personal server.

internet <> wifi router <> terminal_1 <> ethernet <> terminal_2

I have tried following:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-network-interfaces-bridge-eth0-eth1-eth2/
&
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-ubuntu-debian-squeeze-dhcp-server-setup-tutorial/
&
http://www.webupd8.org/2009/02/ubuntu-internet-connection-sharing.html